# what is the real use of a toString() function in a typical model in a real production app? sping Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

There is a code mentioned with creating a typical model for User in Java that I don't understand why it is used.

for example a model for a User would be like that

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique= true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;
private boolean enabled;    
private String secret;

public User() {
    super();
    this.secret = Base32.random();
    this.enabled = false;
}

// getters and setters
}
```

But the issue that I find in a lot of tutorials that we should add this in addition:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final User user = (User) obj;
    if (!email.equals(user.email)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the toString function too

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("User [id=").append(id).append(", firstName=").append(firstName).append(", lastName=").append(lastName).append(", email=").append(email).append(", password=").append(password).append(", enabled=").append(enabled).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Why this code is added to the model? What could be the reason behind it? is it mandatory?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: These methods are not at all mandatory. They are used only when required. You can omit them for simple app.

Comment: You add the `equals(...)` implemenentation in order to determine whether two `User`s are equal.

Comment: You don't understand why having properly defined equality and a descriptive `toString()` would be useful? In **any** class?

Comment: what is the real use of a toString in a real production app?

Comment: If only for the logs of `info` or `error` level, that is a huge benefit! You can put in that `toString()` method all the relevant data about your objects

Comment: thank you it is really helpful @DamCx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toString` is used to print the output for example

Without `toString`

```
class Student{  
 int rollno;  
 String name;  
 String city;  

 Student(int rollno, String name, String city){  
 this.rollno=rollno;  
 this.name=name;  
 this.city=city;  
 }  

 public static void main(String args[]){  
   Student s1=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  
   Student s2=new Student(102,"Krishna","Chennai");  

   System.out.println(s1);
   System.out.println(s2);
 }  
}
```

Output:

```
Student@7852e922
Student@4e25154f
```

In this example, `s1` and `s2` printed the location, not the field values

With `toString`

```
class Student{  
 int rollno;  
 String name;  
 String city;  

 Student(int rollno, String name, String city){  
 this.rollno=rollno;  
 this.name=name;  
 this.city=city;  
 }  

 public String toString(){//overriding the toString() method  
  return rollno+" "+name+" "+city;  
 }  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
   Student s1=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  
   Student s2=new Student(102,"Krishna","Chennai");  

   System.out.println(s1);
   System.out.println(s2);
 }  
}
```

Output:

```
101 Ram Bengaluru
102 Krishna Chennai
```

In this example, it printed the field values as expected.

For `equals` method
Without `equals`:

```
class Student{  
 int rollno;  
 String name;  
 String city;  

 Student(int rollno, String name, String city){  
 this.rollno=rollno;  
 this.name=name;  
 this.city=city;  
 }  

 public static void main(String args[]){  
   Student s1=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  
   Student s2=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  

   System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
 }

}
```

Output:
false

In this example, though s1 and s2 i.e.

```
   Student s1=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  
   Student s2=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");
```

are same, still the result of s1.equals(s2) is false.

With `equals`

```
class Student {  
     int rollno;  
     String name;  
     String city;  

     Student(int rollno, String name, String city){  
     this.rollno=rollno;  
     this.name=name;  
     this.city=city;  
     }  

     public static void main(String args[]){  
       Student s1=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  
       Student s2=new Student(101,"Ram","Bengaluru");  

       System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
     }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (city == null) {
            if (other.city != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!city.equals(other.city))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (rollno != other.rollno)
            return false;
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Output:
true

In this example, result of `s1.equals(s2)` is correct i.e. true