# Why we use Object handler object in parameter list of spring mvc interceptor methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. In preHandle interceptor method we use parameters like ***HttpServeltRequest req***, ***HttpServletResponse res*** and ***Object handler***. I know that Object class is the most supreme class in java but still, I have no idea why we are using ***Object handler*** object.

My eclipse ide showing some suggestions of ***toString()***, ***equals()*** etc methods with ***handler*** object. I don't know how to use them with ***handler*** object.

Somebody please give the uses of ***Object handler***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Object handler** is the chosen handler object to handle the request. This method can throw Exception also, in that case Spring MVC Exception Handling should be useful to send error page as response.

The **toString()** method returns the string representation of the object.

The **equals()** method compares the two given strings based on the content of the string. If any character is not matched, it returns false. If all characters are matched, it returns true.

Follow this
[what is the real use of a toString() function in a typical model in a real production app? sping Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249922/what-is-the-real-use-of-a-tostring-function-in-a-typical-model-in-a-real-produ)

Comment: Hi @ddmmcc, I don't know how to use **handler** object with these methods.  I am trying to print **handler.toString()** but I am getting no output on console.

Comment: Attach your code(controller class and jsp file)